# Prove that a set is closed.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $X$ a metric space, $A\subseteq X$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define :
>   $$A_n =\{ x\in X \mid d(x;X-A)\geq \frac{1}{n} \}$$
>   where $d(x;X-A)$ is the distance from $x$ to the set $X-A$.
>
> Prove that $A_n$ is closed for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Mi proof, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ :

Consider $x_0 \in X-A$ and the set : $C_{x_0} = \{ x \in X\mid d(x,x_o) \geq \frac{1}{n} \}$. It is immediate to see that:

$$ X-C_{x_0} = B_{(x_0,\frac{1}{n})} $$

where $ B_{(x_0,\frac{1}{n})} = \{x \in X \mid d(x,x_0)<\frac{1}{n} \} $. 
Since the open ball is open, we have to $C_{x_0}$ is closed. Finally :

$$ A_n = \bigcap_{x_0 \in X-A} C_{x_0} $$

is closed because it is an arbitrary intersection of closed sets.

The equality $$A_n = \bigcap_{x_0 \in X-A} C_{x_0} $$ is true because :

If $x\in A_n$ :

$\implies \frac{1}{n} \leq d(x,X-A) \leq d(x,x_0), \forall x_0 \in X-A$

$ \implies x \in C_{x_0}, \forall x_0 \in X-A $.

$\implies x\in \bigcap C_{x_0}$

Conversely if $x \in \bigcap C_{x_0}$

$ \implies x \in C_{x_0}, \forall x_0 \in X-A $

$\implies d(x,x_0)\geq \frac{1}{n}, \forall x_0 \in X-A $

$\implies d(x,X-A)\geq \frac{1}{n}$

$\implies x\in A_n$

Is my proof correct? Thanks!

NOTE : If $A$ is compact is true that $$A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n ?$$

Comment: What you have looks correct to me.  I think you should justify the last equality $A_n = \cap C_{x_0}$.  In particular, you should explain how you get $A_n \supseteq \cap C_{x_0}$.  (I think that inclusion would not be true if you replaced all your $\geq$ symbols with $>$.)

Comment: As to the final question: for $A=[-2,2]$, $A_n = [-2+\frac1n, 2-\frac1n]$, whose union is $(-2,2)$ not $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to that brute force proof.

f:X -> R, x -> d(x,X - A) is continuous.
I = { x in R : 1/n <= x } is closed.
$A_n = f^{-1}(I)$
is the inverse image of a closed set by a continuous function,
hence closed.